# Is it advisable to split this process into different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, directory

I have a Java application that is designed to run on removable devices. One feature of it is that it is designed to list all of the folders on the drive, but obviously the more files and folders there are the more time it will take (regardless of how powerful the computer is) and with removal devices getting bigger and bigger these days, I think it is important to gain as much speed in this process as possible.

I know that the best/quickest (in terms of listing, not coding) way would be to create an index file, but I think that misses the point of what my application is all about. So, I thought maybe threads would help because in theory, even two would double the speed of listing, but I don't know if this is possible, and if so how?

Any answers would be appreciated. Here is the recursive method that I currently have:

```
private static void recursiveNodeCreation(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, String root){
        if(root==null) root = RUNNING_DRIVE = ".";

        try{
        // Get a list of files/folders in the root directory
        File rootDir = new File(root);

        File[] files = rootDir.listFiles();
        // Loop through the files/folders
        for(File current : files){
            if(Files.isReadable(current.toPath()) && !current.isHidden() && current.isDirectory()){
                DefaultMutableTreeNode folder = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new FolderOnDrive(current.getName(), current.getPath()));
                recursiveNodeCreation(folder, current.getPath());
                node.add(folder);
            }
        }
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

(`RUNNING_DRIVE` holds the drive letter of the drive that the application is running on. I just added `= "."` to make it quicker whilst testing. As you may have guessed, I'm listing all the folders in a JTree.)

Comment: @Grey I'm not waiting for the device to respond. It's just the process of actually recursively going in and out of every directory takes time - I suppose it is how many directories that are nested which actually makes the difference but nevertheless, I'd like to speed this process up!

Comment: I've moved my comment out to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threading an application will improve the speed of the application if multiple operations can be performed *in parallel*.  For example, if you are reading and writing from a single network connection, it makes sense to fork a thread so that you can handle other connections at the same time.

In your case, however, I suspect that you are being limited by your removable device's ability to service IO requests.  Every device (including memory) has a maximum number of requests and a maximum amount of data that it can handle in a time period -- regardless of the number of threads.  Memory sticks and the like are notoriously slow which is why many cameras have memory inside themselves to they can take a number of pictures quickly while writing to the SD card over time.  Adding additional threads will most likely not improve the overall application performance and may actually slow it down because the IO requests will be working on different parts of the storage drive and competing with each other.

One way to have your application seem more performant is to have one thread do the actual reading of the device in the background.  Then your UI can show the initial results to the user (like the top directory) and fill in more information as the background thread reads in from the device.

To test to see if you are IO bound, you should run your code on a faster hard drive to compare it's directory recursion speed with the removable device.

Comment: So really what your saying is that even though I could split it into new threads, each thread would just get queued up because the removal device can't deal with multiple threads reading the same file at the same - even though I am just reading directories? And if this is so, can't Windows read a file whilst another application is using it and vice versa?

Comment: It's not about multiple threads @Andy.  It's about maximum IO rate.  Every device has the maximum about of data and requests that it can handle per unit of time.  Once you are reading a device as fast as it can be read, adding an additional thread won't make it go faster.

Comment: @Andy Can you run your application on a local hard drive instead of the removable storage?  If it runs faster then you are limited by the removable device IO speeds.

Comment: @Andy Correction: "Every device has the maximum _amount_ of data and requests that it can handle per unit of time. "

Comment: Ok yes - I understand. So will one thread read the device at the maximum rate or do I need multiple threads to take advantage of the device's potential? Also, what is actually the best way for me to tackle this situation in your opinion?

Comment: One thread should be more than enough to max out the IO chain @Andy.  Have you tried the test with local hard disk?  At the end of my answer I give an idea.  Otherwise you will have to wait for it.  There is no easy answer.

Comment: Just counting in my head, @Gray, reading from my SSD is at least 5 seconds faster than reading the exact same content from my USB 2.0 drive!...

Comment: I'm surprised that it isn't faster @Andy.  SSDs are 2 to 3 orders of magnitude faster than SATA drives and I would guess that USB2.0 is a lot slower than SATA.

Comment: It probably is @Gray - I was just roughly counting in my head. Anyway, is the idea you gave the only way you can think of to make the listing faster without using indexing. By the way, I'm not displaying the JTree until all of the nodes have been added. Also, how come the windows directory selector doesn't take that long to load the directories on removal devices?

Comment: @Andy, the windows directory server probably doesn't load all of the directories.  It loads the top one and you have to click to get the subdirectories.  That is what you should be doing.

Comment: I will try that, maybe that will speed things up a bit. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: One last question @Gray. Do you know if Windows actually indexes removable drives by default?

Answer (score 1):

IO is really slow. [This article describes how to tune File IO for performance](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/PerfTuning/), but since your program isn't reading the contents of any file, I doubt you can speed it up.  The bottleneck of your program isn't how fast you can list the Files, its how fast you can get the list of the Files from the device.

You can add as many threads as you want and the bottleneck will still be the IO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too Ivan. That's basically what Gray said in a nutshell and it looks disappointingly very true. Thanks for the link as well